# limit for Ajax calls on a web page?

Tags: ajax

Is there any limit to number of ajax calls on a web page ?
Will it affect the performance of the web application if we have too many ajax calls/timers that have been set to run at frequent interval  .

Regards,
Mithun

Comment: If you have many users and many AJAX calls, it will take a huge hit on your server. Be careful. Use JSON to reduce bandwidth. Try to club multiple AJAX calls into a single one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the browser. Firefox has a default of 2 open requests per host, the rest will be queued. It is configurable, but hardly anyone changes the default.

I'm unsure of other browsers, but google might help if you need the numbers.